# How to render a vnode (slot of a vue component) and mount it on an element?

Tags: vue.js

For example, here we have a dialog component.

```
...

<dialog>
  <div>
   {{data}}
  </div>
</dialog>

...
```

As we known, due to the stack context, it's hard to make the dialog always be the topmost element.

So we need to mount the dialog element as a body's child.

I tried this in dialog's mounted hook.

```
var slot=this.$slots.default
var vm = new Vue({
        render: ()=>slot
}
var div=document.createElement('div')
document.body.append(div)
vm.mount(div)
```

The result is: it mounted successfully.

However, when I changed the data, the mounted vm didn't change.

I wonder how to make it reactive or is there any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I can't find any methods to solve this.
I have to read some open source ui framework's source code because I know they do put the dialog in the body's child level.

And I found that they do render the `<slot>`, but I can't find any code rendered in the corresponding position and I can't find any code they use to 'remove' it.

...

Then, I found a line of code, `document.body.append(this.$el)`. I am stupid. I didn't realize that `append` will just remove the element from it's original position and append  it to the new position util I re-read the whole code once again.

I did think about this way, just append $el to somewhere. But I am afraid that it'll break the component down.

### So, the solution is:

1. just define a normal vue component
2. ship the $el or child element to anywhere you want using `element.append` etc. after the component mounted
3. no need to remove the element manually when component is destroyed if you just ship the $el, vue will take care of it.